# make my secure server work with firebase cloud messaging (open ports on firewall)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firewall

I am Building an Andriod mobile application and I am deploying it on my client server. My client is a telecommunication company with a very secure server. Once We deployed the app, we found out the the firebase cloud messaging is not working. I am sure that the problem is with the client firewall. Could you please advice me how to solve this problem. Looking forward to here your comments and suggestions. Thanks

Comment: I'm flagging this question as too broad. "the firebase cloud messaging is not working" and you seem to just assume that the firewall is the problem. You'll need to provide a lot more detail here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A simple test is to take a device and connect outside the firewall and see if it works. Then, once you know that, you can proceed with troubleshooting. This question is not about programming, nor is any code included.

Answer (score 0):

You need yo open poet 5228-5230. FCM documentation has this info,